# Need to carry on browser "session" when calling another php script through CURL

Tags: php, session, curl

I have a "primary" PHP script (actually a set of scripts) all of whom the user interacts with through the browser. I've had no problems using the site as the session information works from page to page.

However, one of the scripts needs to directly call another "secondary" php script on my site using CURL and that "secondary" script needs to get information about the php session (which contains the currently logged in user, etc) from the "primary". I need to pass on the session information from the "primary" php script to the "secondary" one in CURL. Any suggestions on how I can do that?

No, I dont want to use cookies here (too insecure).

Comment: Why is cURL required? What about `virtual()` (assuming you're on Apache), `include()` or `require()`?

Comment: yes if you are on the same server why not just using the normal include mechanism.

Comment: I'm using CURL because the secondary php script takes GET variables and returns some values which the primary php script needs.

Comment: and making a function won't be better ???

Comment: Hi RageZ - no, the php file is called with GET variables from another source as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you don't want to use cookies because they're insecure. In the following solution, the client side session cookie is "forwarded" on to a second request. Forwarding a cookie to the local machine should create no security disadvantages.

You can pass the session cookie from the client browser to the new, server-side request (thanks to Ben for pointing out `session_name`).

```
$curl_cookies = session_name() . '=' . session_id() . '; path=/';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $curl_cookies);
```

For simplicity, I'm only passing in the PHPSESSID cookie (I'm also assuming it is your session's cookie key).

Comment: Hi Brian, Ben - I'm working on your suggestions, but am sending the session_id() as a GET parameter to my "secondary" script. However, when I do the following in the second script and try to load the first one, the browser just hangs and does not load the page.

$sessionid = urldecode($_GET['sessionid']);
session_id($sessionid);
session_start();

What do I need to do to tell the second script to use the first one's session?

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions are tied to cookies (although [can also be passed as a request parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)).  So for forwarding the session ID, cookie might be the best way to go assuming both scripts are in the same PHP installation.

You can use [session_name()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) to get the session name/cookie name, which is by default PHPSESSID like Brian pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

why not just send an http query string parameter with the session id in it?

for instance (in pseudocode):

curl.send('http://myserver.com/myapplication.php?session_id=' . getSessionId());